# Yocto PACKAGECONFIG option not being applied

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded, iio

I am trying to add [libiio](https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/libiio) to my Yocto image, and I'm using the [libiio](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/57509/) recipe from `meta-oe`. The library seems to be added, however I can't seem to enable the python bindings.

In that recipe, there are the lines

```auto
PACKAGECONFIG ??= " \
    usb_backend network_backend serial_backend xml_backend \
    ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'zeroconf', 'dnssd', '', d)} \
"

# ...

PACKAGECONFIG[libiio-python3] = "-DPYTHON_BINDINGS=ON,-DPYTHON_BINDINGS=OFF"
```

I have a bbappend file `libiio_%.bbappend` with:

```auto
PACKAGECONFIG:append = " libiio-python3"
```

Running `bitbake -e libiio | grep PACKAGECONFIG` returns.

```auto
PACKAGECONFIG="     usb_backend network_backend serial_backend xml_backend     dnssd  libiio-python3"
```

In the `log.do_confiure` file, there are these lines:

```
-- Found Python: /home/<name>/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/libiio/0.23-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/python3-native/python3 (found version "3.10.9") found components: Interpreter 
-- new
-- Python_EXECUTABLE /home/<name>/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/libiio/0.23-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/python3-native/python3
-- Found Python: Building bindings
```

And in the `log.do_install` file, there are these lines:

```
writing pylibiio.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to pylibiio.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to pylibiio.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'pylibiio.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'pylibiio.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
Copying pylibiio.egg-info to /home/<name>/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/libiio/0.23-r0/image/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pylibiio-0.23-py3.10.egg-info
```

But the python bindings are not part of the built image.

How do I enable a feature using `PACKAGECONFIG`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install `libiio-python3`?  The recipe puts the python bindings into a separate package.

Answer (score 1):

add a space; e.g.

```
PACKAGECONFIG:append = " libiio-python3"
```

Comment: Adding the space does not seem to change anything, the python bindings are still not included.

Comment: I have updated my question and your answer is no longer applicable